# Ubuntu Mobile Operating System

Tags: kernel

Is there any way to install Ubuntu Mobile in Samsung Wave devices? As you all know, Bada is not an open source and it might be hard to get the exact drivers. However, if anyone have any idea about this topic, please replay for this post.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

take a look [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2162770&highlight=ubuntu), there is development, but it looks it is in alpha. A general list of devices with ubuntu touch can be found [here](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/is-there-a-ubuntu-touch-build-for-your-device/).